# List view still showing removed item

Tags: android

My adapter item is removed in arraylist but listview not updating still showing deleted item from database. it has bug only when navigated from other fragments to this fragment.

any help please. dunno where went wrong. have been calling 
following is my fragment file.

```
public class SupplierViewFragment extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<Supplier> suppliers = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView lvListView;
    FunDapter adapter;
    ListView lvSupplierList;
    TextView tvSupplierViewMessage;
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    ViewPager pager;

    private AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
    BindDictionary<Supplier> dictionary = new BindDictionary<>();

    public SupplierViewFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_supplier_view, container, false);
        tvSupplierViewMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSupplierViewMessage);
        tvSupplierViewMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        getData("supplier-view-servlet");
        dictionary = new BindDictionary<>();
        dictionary.addStringField(R.id.tvSupplierListID, new StringExtractor<Supplier>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(Supplier item, int position) {
                return "ID: " + item.getSupplierID();
            }
        });
        dictionary.addStringField(R.id.tvSupplierListCompanyName, new StringExtractor<Supplier>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(Supplier item, int position) {
                return item.getSupplierCompanyName();
            }
        });
        dictionary.addStringField(R.id.tvSupplierListName, new StringExtractor<Supplier>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(Supplier item, int position) {
                return "(" + item.getSupplierName() + ")";
            }
        });
        dictionary.addStringField(R.id.tvSupplierListAddress, new StringExtractor<Supplier>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(Supplier item, int position) {
                return  item.getSupplierAddress();
            }
        });
        dictionary.addStringField(R.id.tvSupplierListTelp, new StringExtractor<Supplier>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(Supplier item, int position) {
                return  item.getSupplierTelp();
            }
        });
        dictionary.addStringField(R.id.tvSupplierListMobile, new StringExtractor<Supplier>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(Supplier item, int position) {
                return  item.getSupplierMobile();
            }
        });
        dictionary.addStringField(R.id.tvSupplierListEmail, new StringExtractor<Supplier>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(Supplier item, int position) {
                return  item.getSupplierEmail();
            }
        });
        dictionary.addStringField(R.id.tvSupplierListCity, new StringExtractor<Supplier>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(Supplier item, int position) {
                return  getCityName("cities-servlet?city-id=" + item.getSupplierCity());
            }
        });
        dictionary.addStringField(R.id.tvSupplierListCountry, new StringExtractor<Supplier>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(Supplier item, int position) {
                return  getCountryName("countries-servlet?city-id=" + item.getSupplierCity());
            }
        });

        adapter = new FunDapter(SupplierViewFragment.this.getActivity(),suppliers,R.layout.supplier_list_layout,dictionary);
        lvSupplierList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvSupplierView);
        lvSupplierList.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        registerForContextMenu(lvSupplierList);
        pager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);

        return view;
    }

    public void refreshApi(){
        suppliers.clear();
        adapter.resetData();

        getData("supplier-view-servlet");
        lvSupplierList.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lvSupplierList.invalidate();
        //adapter = new FunDapter(SupplierViewFragment.this.getActivity(),suppliers,R.layout.supplier_list_layout,dictionary);

        Log.d("REFRESH", suppliers.size()+" -------------------");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        String text = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.supplier_view_delete_id:

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SupplierViewFragment.this.getActivity());

                builder.setMessage("Are sure to delete selected supplier?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                Supplier supplier = new Supplier(suppliers.get(info.position).getSupplierID());

                                try {
                                    Log.d("Supplier Size:",suppliers.size() + "to delete:" + info.position);

                                    deleteData("supplier-delete-servlet?supplier-id=" + supplier.getSupplierID() );
                                    suppliers.clear();
                                    refreshApi();
                                    Log.d("Supplier AFTER:",suppliers.size() + "to delete:" + info.position);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                                    pager.setCurrentItem(0);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                Toast.makeText(SupplierViewFragment.this.getActivity(),"Supplier Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No",null);
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();

                return true;

            case R.id.supplier_view_edit_id:

                //StaffEditFragment staffEditFragment = new StaffEditFragment.newInstance("Some1","Some2");
                Log.d("Current Position:",""+info.position);
                Supplier supplierEdit = suppliers.get(info.position);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("supplierID",supplierEdit.getSupplierID());
                SupplierEditFragment supplierEditFragment = new SupplierEditFragment();

                supplierEditFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,supplierEditFragment);
                ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Edit Supplier");
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.supplier_context_menu,menu);
    }

    public void deleteData(String servletAddress){
        JsonRequestHelper requestHelper = new JsonRequestHelper();
        JSONArray jsonArray = requestHelper.getJsonArrayViaGET(servletAddress);
    }
    public String getCountryName(String servletAddress){
        String countryName = null;
        try {
            JsonRequestHelper requestHelper = new JsonRequestHelper();
            JSONArray jsonArray = requestHelper.getJsonArrayViaGET(servletAddress);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                countryName = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("country-name").toString();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("cityName:",countryName);
        return countryName;
    }

    public String getCityName(String servletAddress){
        String cityName = null;
        try {
            JsonRequestHelper requestHelper = new JsonRequestHelper();
            JSONArray jsonArray = requestHelper.getJsonArrayViaGET(servletAddress);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                cityName = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("city-name").toString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("cityName:",cityName);
        return cityName;
    }

    public void getData(String servletAddress){
        JsonRequestHelper requestHelper = new JsonRequestHelper();
        JSONArray jsonArray = requestHelper.getJsonArrayViaGET(servletAddress);
        Supplier supplier = new Supplier();
        if (jsonArray == null) {
            //Log.d("Reach000","#####################");
            tvSupplierViewMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvSupplierViewMessage.setText("Error Connecting Database");
            Toast.makeText(SupplierViewFragment.this.getActivity(), "Error Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            tvSupplierViewMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            tvSupplierViewMessage.setText("");
            try {

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    supplier = new Supplier();
                    supplier.setSupplierID(Integer.parseInt(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("id").toString()));
                    supplier.setSupplierCompanyName(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("company-name").toString());
                    supplier.setSupplierName(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("name").toString());
                    supplier.setSupplierAddress(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("address").toString());
                    supplier.setSupplierCity(Integer.parseInt(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("city-id").toString()));
                    supplier.setSupplierEmail(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("email").toString());
                    supplier.setSupplierTelp(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("telp").toString());
                    supplier.setSupplierMobile(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("mobile").toString());

                    suppliers.add(supplier);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post FunDapter?

Comment: I just initilized FunDapter using this line: adapter = new FunDapter(SupplierViewFragment.this.getActivity(),suppliers,R.layout.supplier_list_layout,dictionary);

Comment: Are you deleting the record from db as well?

Comment: record is deleted via deleteData("supplier-delete-servlet?supplier-id=" + supplier.getSupplierID() ); record successfully deleted but listview not updated. this bug occurs only when i have clicked on other fragment then navigate back to this SupplierViewFragment. if start activity from this fragment everything work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by replacing it as a new fragment everytime it deletes an item. not sure if it's the right way but at least work for the moments. Thanks for the response guys. hope it helps for others looking for similiar problems.

fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new SupplierFragment());
                ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("View Supplier");
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

```
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a updateDataset(ArrayList suppliers) method in adapter and call it whenever you want to update listview content.

Add below method in adapter,

```
public void updateDataset(ArrayList<Supplier> suppliers) {
this.suppliers = suppliers;
notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

When you delete item from database,fetch new data and call,

```
adapter.updateDataset(ArrayList<Supplier> suppliers)
```

Comment: Still not updating the list.